# reverse on array - got returned function:IBMJS built-in function

Tags: arrays, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to reverse an array e.g.

```
<xp:text escape="true" >
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.reverse();}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
```

but I get returned:

function:IBMJS built-in function

How can  perform a reverse on array via SSJS in xpages?

Comment: I think it is working (as in it's reversing the contents of the array). If you return fruits.join(" "); as the result of your computed field it will show "Mango Apple Orange Banana" (See this link too. Not XPages - but same issue http://ibm.software.network.directory-integrator.narkive.com/i0I2h3Rp/array-s-reverse-method-cannot-be-used-in-tdi)

Comment: @MartinPerrie: I think your comment provides the correct answer. You should post it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Re-posting my comment as an answer as suggested by @xpages-noob

I think it is working (as in it's reversing the contents of the array). If you return fruits.join(" "); as the result of your computed field it will show "Mango Apple Orange Banana" (See this link too. Not XPages - but same issue http://ibm.software.network.directory-integrator.narkive.com/i0I2h3Rp/array-s-reverse-method-cannot-be-used-in-tdi)